# How to add a module, which is not inside the project folder, to an Android Gradle Project?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I have a quite large project with several subprojects. It looks similiar to this:

```
trunk/
    App1/
    App2/
    AndroidLibrary1/
    AndroidLibrary2/
    JavaLib/
    ...
```

At the moment everything is build with maven and I develop in eclipse. Now we would like to switch to gradle and Android Studio.

My first attempt was to import every libraryProject as own Project in AndroidStudio which leads to a lot of seperate AndroidStudio Windows. Also when I change something in a library I need to run `gradle install` first and then build the seperate App Project again, which pulls the lib from the local maven repo. Instead of this I would like to be able to access all projects from one AndroidStudio Window and start a build for all included libraries.

As far as I understand one solution to have all "Projects" in one AndroidStudio window would be to copy all libraries to App1 and then add them as submodules. My problem with this approach is that I would have duplicated code in App1 and App2.

Is there a way to add a submodule to a project and display its code in AndroidStudio, so I can work on it and the app at the same time, but not have to copy it? e.g. something similiar to `compile project ./../LibA`